# Spying a call made to a method of a dependency in NodeJs (Chai)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have an application where I have a Controller called `NotesController` and a service injected in it called `NotesService` which I use to retrieve notes.

I am trying to write a unit test for my Controller using spies from Chai library:

```
chai.use(spies);

describe('Notes Controller', () => {
   chai.spy.on(notesController, 'notesService.get', (id) => id);
}

describe('Get note by id', () => {
    it('Retrieves note successfully', (done) => {
      notesController.get("1")
        .then(() => {
            chai.expect('notesService.get').to.have.been.called();
         })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            done(error)
        });
  }
}
```

My test fails because for some reason it tries to run that method `notesService.get`, so it fails when it tries to connect to the DB.

How can I mock this method call (`notesService.get`) using spies instead of actually running it?

Comment: What chai plugin are you using? Where do `spies` come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies/

Comment: Show the code under test